# Manual resolve Unity dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

Is possible make a Resolve<> inside a method instead inject the dependency in the constructor or in a property of the class?

```
public void Foo()
{
    if (...)
        var context = Unity.Resolve<Context>();
}
```

The idea is a conditional dependency resolve that uses the Unity to manage the lifetime of the object created as in the usual DI usage. The DI is set in a Web Api project so the MVC DependencyResolver.Current will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is considered a bad pattern by some, you can implement a form of simple static Service Locator pattern like this:

```
public static class Unity
{
    private static IUnityContainer _container;

    public static void SetAppContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the Web Api has some built in feature like the MVC DependencyResolver.Current (wich makes the same as your code).

Comment: Yes it does. We've used it before. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: I'm using this solution too but it requires the container object to be stored to all application scope so your solution is required on top of the built in Unity. When the config.DependencyInjection is set to UnityResolver I can't access this property to take the current DI and work with it.

Comment: It looks like I can make this work using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver to access the UnityResolver and just cast the type of object. I will take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea. The only part of your application that should have knowledge of your container is the composition root. This is an example of a service locator which is an anti-pattern, because dependencies aren't explicitly declared.

It sounds like you want to introduce a factory type that can be injected via constructor injection.

Comment: Yes, this is an anti-pattern but I have one situation where this is desireble due performance.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: One situation is in authentication using tokens: 99% of the time in my application the token works without database access so I didn't require a new Context (it's ship of course but in scale could be a problem). In normal situation the constructor injection should always be used.

Comment: It sounds like your authentication infrastructure needs restructuring. You shouldn't require any service locator for the majority of areas within Web API. Are you using OAuth and claims based authentication? In which case you should have some endpoint which is used for sign in, which does your database check, and then all other end points that require authentication should have the current users set of claims on the current users principal. Could you explain more about which type requires a context and why?